# How to sort translated modelform fields alphabetically

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to sort translated field names alphabetically. How could I modify the code below to achieve this? Currently this code translates the verbose name. Now, I'd like to know how to order the translated field names alphabetically. The site will be available in multiple languages.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class User_interest(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    acting = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Acting'),default=False)
    aikido = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Aikido'),default=False)
    airhockey = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Air Hockey'),default=False)
    airsoft = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Airsoft'),default=False)
    americanfootball = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('American Football'),default=False)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

forms.py

```
class InterestsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User_interest
        exclude = ['user']
```

template.html

```
<ul>
    {% for interest in interests %}

        <li>
             {{ interest }} {{ interest.label }}
        </li>

     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot help you directly to your question on how to sort the fields, and I hope somebody can. But alternatively I would like to share my experience:

Whenever you find yourself wondering about how to accomplish such tasks, take a step back and wonder if an improvement in your data modelling would improve your situation.

So instead, you could replace all these fields with a new model `Interests` and a [many-to-many field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) in `User_interest`. This way sorting is piece of cake, plus you have dynamic interests vs. hard-coded ones.

When many-to-many fields are rendered in forms, [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) is used, which takes a QuerySet as its first parameter that can be sorted in any way.